# Binding event handlers in React Components fires onClick when rendered

Tags: reactjs, event-handling

I am learning React. In a test app I'm writing, I am rendering some buttons with onClick methods. When they are rendered like this, they work and call the selectMode function as expected when clicked.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { mode: 'commits', commits: [], forks: [], pulls: [] };
}    
...
selectMode(mode) {
    this.setState({ mode });
}    

render() {
...
return (<div>                
        <button onClick={this.selectMode.bind(this, 'commits')}>Show Commits</button><br/>
        <button onClick={this.selectMode.bind(this, 'forks')}>Show Forks</button><br/>
        <button onClick={this.selectMode.bind(this, 'pulls')}>Show Pulls</button>
        </div>
        )
}
```

But when I tried the suggested best practices way shown below, by binding in the constructor, the selectMode function is called three times when the component is rendered. Why are the onClick event handlers being called then? What do I have wrong?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { mode: 'commits', commits: [], forks: [], pulls: [] };
    this.selectMode = this.selectMode.bind(this)
}
...
selectMode(mode) {
    this.setState({ mode });
}

render() {
...
return (<div>                
        <button onClick={this.selectMode('commits')}>Show Commits</button><br/>
        <button onClick={this.selectMode('forks')}>Show Forks</button><br/>
        <button onClick={this.selectMode('pulls')}>Show Pulls</button>
        </div>
        )
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your `this.selectMode(...)` is executed IMMEDIATELY whenever your component is rendered.

```
<.. onClick={this.selectMode('commits')}..../> <-- function is called immediately
```

You can use `arrow function` to create an anonymous function in which you can call your method. In this way, you `this.selectMode` method only get called when the click event occurs :

```
<.. onClick={() => this.selectMode('commits')}..../>
```

If you don't want to create anonymous functions everytime you render the component, you can store an value to an attribute of the element. Like this :

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = { mode: 'commits', commits: [], forks: [], pulls: [] };
 this.selectMode = this.selectMode.bind(this)
}
selectMode(event){
    this.setState({mode: e.target.name});
}
render(){
....
   <.. onClick={this.selectMode} name='commits' ..../> 
..}
```

Comment: Using an attribute of the element is a nice way to pass these parameters. I'm too new to have thought of that, and no example that I saw covered passing parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I think it's because you call upon each onClick function by adding the parentheses. If you use ES6 you could try doing this:

```
onClick = () => { this.selectMode('commits') }
onClick = () => { this.selectMode('forks') }
onClick = () => { this.selectMode('pulls') }
```

Comment: Yes, the arrow functions work with extra enclosing braces as shown:    <button onClick ={ () => { this.selectMode('commits') } }>Show Commits</button>. This is presented in the react docs. But I was trying to not use arrow functions. My way is also in the React docs (but never shown passing parameters).